# How to map values of string type array with int type array in Golang?

Tags: arrays, string, go, int, mapping

I want to know how to map each element of board with respective element of change.

```golang
func convert () {  
        var i,j,k int   
        k = 1  
        change := [64]int {}  
        board := [8][8]string{}  

       for i = 0; i < 8; i++ {  
            for j = 0; j < 8; j++ {  
                board[i][j] = string(i+65) + string(j+49)  
                fmt.Print(board[i][j] ," ")  
            }  
            fmt.Println()  
        }    
        fmt.Println()  

        for i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++ {
                change[i] = k
                k++
              fmt.Print(change[i] ," ")
            }
        fmt.Println()
      }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of mapping are you looking for exactly? Do you mean conversion to a single dimensional array?

Comment: I want to map A1 to 1, A2 to 2,...B1 to 9,.....H8 to 64 @abhink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int(s[0]-'A')*8 + int(s[1]-'0')` like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(toNumber("A1")) // 1
    fmt.Println(toNumber("A2")) // 2
    fmt.Println(toNumber("B1")) // 9
    fmt.Println(toNumber("H8")) // 64
    convert()
}
func toNumber(s string) int {
    if len(s) != 2 {
        panic("len(string) != 2")
    }
    return int(s[0]-'A')*8 + int(s[1]-'0')
}
func convert() {
    change := [64]int{}
    board := [8][8]string{}
    k := 0
    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            board[i][j] = string(i+65) + string(j+49)
            fmt.Print(board[i][j], " ")
            change[k] = toNumber(board[i][j])
            k++
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    fmt.Println()

    for i := 0; i < 64; i++ {
        fmt.Print(change[i], " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

output:

```
1
2
9
64
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 
D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 
G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 
H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map instead of a slice for `change`:

```
change := make(map[int]string)

for i = 0; i < 8; i++ {  
    for j = 0; j < 8; j++ {  
        board[i][j] = string(i+65) + string(j+49)
        // map 1->A1, 2->A2...64->H8
        change[i*8 + j+1] = board[i][j]
        fmt.Print(board[i][j] ," ")  
    }    
}
```

There shouldn't be any need for the second loop.

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/VOGhNpiG3g